# How can I determine the macOS 10.14 accent color?

Tags: macos, user-interface, colors, custom-controls

MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) features a Dark interface style, and user selectable color accents. How to read these values and listen for changes?

Edit: Now with macOS 11 there have been introduced new M1 iMacs with their own unique color scheme. I have access to such an iMac and have not been able to determine the accent color. It is a yellow version and the AppleAccentColor is reported as "1" which translates to orange.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is stored in the system defaults, available through `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`.

Dark mode is active when `AppleInterfaceStyle` is set to `Dark`. Changes can be observed by listening for the `InterfaceStyleChanged` notification.

The accent color can be read from `AppleAccentColor`. Changes can be observed by listening for the `AppleColorPreferencesChangedNotification` notification. Both returns an optional integer, that maps to:

```
nil: blue
-1: graphite
0: red
1: orange
2: yellow
3: green
5: purple
6: pink
```

You can read this value from the terminal or a script by running `defaults read -g AppleAccentColor`. Note that if the value is `nil` (default blue) you actually get an error that reads `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleAccentColor) does not exist`.

---

**Update for macOS 11 beta**

`nil` is now the default *multicolor* appearance, and *blue* has been moved to `4`.

```
nil: multicolor
-1: graphite
0: red
1: orange
2: yellow
3: green
4: blue
5: purple
6: pink
```

Comment: I noticed that my app receives the `AppleColorPreferencesChangedNotification` notification not until the second change of the accent color. Can you confirm this @Henrik?

Comment: No, I do not see this behavior.

Comment: `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` does not exist?

Comment: I think you are leaving out some parts of your question, @evolutionxbox. As far as I can tell this does exist, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter

Comment: @Henrik Sorry I was looking for the `defaults read` variant. Which I couldn't find.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was looking for that as well. It's `defaults read -g AppleAccentColor`. Note that if this is set to the default blue, it's actually set to `nil` and you get an error: `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleAccentColor) does not exist`. For future reference, you can run `defaults read` which will output everything. You can then search for the key you know to see its path. Here though it's in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

The accent color is available as `NSColor.controlAccentColor` in macOS 10.14 or newer.

On `NSView` level you can implement event handler `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance()` to track accent color changes.

Comment: `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance()` is called when dark/light mode changes, but it does not appear to be called when the user merely changes the accent or highlight color in the Preferences panel (on MacOS 10.15.5), which is what the OP (original poster) asked about.

Comment: @jsbox At my side, the method is still called when changing the accent color, using macOS 12.5.