# How to tell the name of NSColor controlAccentColor

Tags: cocoa, macos-mojave, nscolor

I'd like to use `[NSColor controlAccentColor]` in a few places, however I would also like to fallback to a special tint of blue when the user selects the Blue system accent color.

How can I reliably detect the type / name of the `controlAccentColor` picked?

Comment: I don't think there's any way, because I doubt the different accent colors have identifiable names (at least not publicly). You could convert accent color to HSB and determine if it's "blue-ish" and then substitute a different blue.

Comment: That's what I was doing till I realised the 'blue' value may not be constant depending on the context. I suppose I'll look out for a more blue-ish color then.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value for the the color with:

```
let accent = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "AppleAccentColor")
```

This returns nil when your system Accent Color is set to blue, or an Int value when it is set to other colors (values listed here: [How can I determine the macOS 10.14 accent color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695755/how-can-i-determine-the-macos-10-14-accent-color/51695756#51695756))

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with this:

```
if (@available(macOS 10.14, *)) {
  NSColor *accentColor = [[NSColor controlAccentColor] colorUsingColorSpace:[NSColorSpace deviceRGBColorSpace]];
  CGFloat redColor, greenColor, blueColor, alphaColor;
  [accentColor getRed:&redColor green:&greenColor blue:&blueColor alpha:&alphaColor];
  if (blueColor == 1 && redColor <= 0.1 && greenColor <= 0.5) {
    // Our special blue
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:52.0 / 255.0 green:109.0 / 255.0 blue:251.0 / 255.0 alpha:0.9]; // pastel blue
  }
  return [NSColor controlAccentColor];
}
```